# Recorrer tabla bootstrap con jQuery text y value HTML5

Tags: jquery, html5, ajax, array, bootstrap-4

Tengo un problema en **jQuery**.
Estoy recorriendo una tabla de **bootstrap** con ciertos valores, necesito que los valores que se corren se guarden en un arreglo, en este momento estoy recorriendo los valores por separado, no sé como puedo hacer para recorrer todos los valores y guardarlos en un `array`.

Quisiera que quedara de la siguiente forma:

```
valores = [modelo, codigo, precio, piezasporcaja, cantidaddepiezas]
```

Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora:

```js
 $("#ok").click(function() {
   info = ""
   $(".valores").parent("tr").find("td").each(function() {
     info += $(this).text() + ",";
     // info += this.value+ " ";
   });

   $('.valores').each(function(e) {
     info += this.value + " ";
   });
   console.log(info);
   alert(info);
 })
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <thead class="thead-light">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Modelo</th>
      <th scope="col">Codigo</th>
      <th scope="col">Precio</th>
      <th scope="col">Piezas por caja</th>
      <th scope="col">Cantidad de Piezas</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class='valores' scope="row">SILENT 100 DESIGN</th>
      <td>5DESIGN100</td>
      <td>$ 62.00 USD</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td> <input type='number' class='form-control valores' name='qtyMulti' value='0' required min='0' max='99999'> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class='valores' scope="row">SILENT 200 DESIGN</th>
      <td>5DESIGN200</td>
      <td>$ 85.00 USD</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td> <input type='number' class='form-control valores' name='qtyMulti' value='0' required min='0' max='99999'> </td>
    </tr>  
  </tbody>
</table>

<input type="button" value="ok" id="ok" class="boton2">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo dandole la clase `valores` a las lineas en lugar de a los th asi:

```js
$("#ok").click(function() {
  var info=[];
  $(".table").find("tr.valores").each(function() {
               var row = [];
               var flag = false;
               $(this).children().each(function() {
                   var input = $(this).find('input');
                   if (input[0]) {
                     if (input.val() > 0) {
                       flag = true;
                       row.push(input.val());
                     }
                   } else {
                  row.push($(this).text() );
                   }
               });             
               if (flag) {
                 info.push(row);
               }
  });
  console.log(info);
  alert(info);
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <thead class="thead-light">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Modelo</th>
      <th scope="col">Codigo</th>
      <th scope="col">Precio</th>
      <th scope="col">Piezas por caja</th>
      <th scope="col">Cantidad de Piezas</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class='valores'>
      <th scope="row">SILENT 100 DESIGN</th>
      <td>5DESIGN100</td>
      <td>$ 62.00 USD</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td> <input type='number' class='form-control valores' name='qtyMulti' value='0' required min='0' max='99999'> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='valores'>
      <th scope="row">SILENT 200 DESIGN</th>
      <td>5DESIGN200</td>
      <td>$ 85.00 USD</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td> <input type='number' class='form-control valores' name='qtyMulti' value='0' required min='0' max='99999'> </td>
    </tr>  
  </tbody>
</table>

<input type="button" value="ok" id="ok" class="boton2">
```

Comment: esta respuesta en muy buena, pero no me trae el valor del input, ¿Tienes alguna idea por qué?

Comment: Ya edite mi respuesta para incluir el input tambien.

Comment: hay alguna manera de que los valores del input no queden al final, si no en el mismo orden de la tabla?, disculpa por las molestias. :)

Comment: Los inputs estan al final de la tabla, entonces siempre van a aparecer al final de cada array

Comment: Oh sí ya quedó excelente, muchísimas gracias. Saludos!

Comment: Tengo una duda amigo, ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que solo se agreguen al arreglo los valores cuando un input sea > 0?

Comment: input.val() te da el valor del input, solo tienes que chequear que sea mayor que 0

Comment: Sí, eso lo hice con esta condición.  `if (input.val() >0) {
                       row.push(input.val());
                       } `, pero eso solo funciona para el input, yo deseo que funcione para toda la fila.

Comment: ¿Tienes alguna idea me ayudarías muchísimo de verdad?

Comment: Asi como lo pusiste esta bien, puedes poner un flag dentro del if y si es true insertas el row, sino no

Comment: En este momento lo tengo así, pero no entra en las dos condiciones `var input = $(this).find('input');
                     if (input.val() >0) {                      
                      
                        flag = true;
                       row.push(input.val());
                        

                     } else {
                      if (flag == true) { 
                     row.push($(this).text());                       
                      }
                     }`

Comment: Tienes que dejarlo igual como esta en mi respuesta.  La condicion para chequear si es mayor que 0 debe de ir dentro de `if(input[0])`

Comment: ¿Eso para que es?, ya trate de varias maneras añadiendo el flag y no me da, podrías ayudarme?

Comment: ya edite mi respuesta

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77049/discussion-between-alanfcm-and-manueel-perezz).

Comment: ¡Dios!, muchísimas gracias hermano, me acabas de sacar de una. Saludos desde donde quiera que estés. ¡Gracias!